# How to set model field data type based on choices?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here in my model I want to set option value based on choice value. How can I do this or any other solutions ?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    option_value_choices = [
        (1, "models.BooleanField"),
        (2, "models.DateField"),
        (3, "models.IntegerField"),
        (4, "models.CharFIeld")
        ]

    option_value_type = models.IntegerField(choices=option_value_choices)
    option_value =  .. ?
```

Comment: Why do you store choices twice？For each model field that has choices set, Django will add a method to retrieve the human-readable name for the field’s current value. You can use `model.get_option_value_type_display()` when you need the string value.

Comment: @Trock I am not asking about how to get the choice string value. I am asking if we can set the data type based on choice value if possible ?

Comment: No. Only one fixed type can be defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible.

But you can add four fields (one for each model field), with nullable option:

Example:

```
    boolean_option_value = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    integer_option_value = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    date_option_value = models.DateField(null=True)
    char_option_value = models.CharField(null=True)
```

So, in your payload, send all four fields as null.

And based on `option_value_type` field, you can fill in the appropriate field.